# Serialization same object and observe different result

Tags: java, memory, serialization

I want to know why when I serialize the **same object** in memory using table :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOutput);
stream.writeObject(m.view()); //view return a string


        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
        byteOutput.flush();
        byteOutput.close();
```

and I run my program several times, I get different results(not a great difference but still a difference)

```
execution 1 :4497
execution 3 :4500
execution 4 :4500
execution 5 :4494
```

m : is an object that contains another object of other classes. I cannot list all classes here, it's a large framework and `string` serialized is the same !

Comment: What are `m` and `overhead`? Maybe try to post a complete SSCCE (http://sscce.org)?

Comment: If the size is not exactly the same, the object is not the same either.

Comment: is same size, it same execution, it same all :)

Comment: `m.view()` is a `String`? Can I suggest pulling that out of the loop, or hardcoding the actual value a literal, and then trying again?

Comment: What do you mean with "different result", what is the number after execution 1: ??? How do you get that number ?

Comment: You get a difference of 6 out of 4500, or 0.133%. I don't know why you consider that significant or even different. It isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your object is `m` from your code it seems you have different states (`overhead`). Since serialization is recursive, not only your object, but all other objects it contains have to be the same.

Please post more information on `m` and it's connection to `overhead` for a more thorough answer.

Comment: yes i know, it take not only my object but all other objects it contains. But, when i run several time, all executions are SAME (same data input, same objects, same environnement, same all).

Answer (score 0):

Something *is* different between your executions, do you use the current time in your object for example ?

You may show us more context, or try to find out by yourself what is different but as long as you say nothing is different but the result you won't find the explanation...

Try to reduce the problem, you say m.view() yields always the same result, how do you know ? If it always returns the same result, hardcode the result in a string and show us that the same string serialized several times gives different results...